# How to delegate two factor for OneLogin's Cloud Directory?

Tags: api, openid, saml, onelogin, multi-factor-authentication

[Cloud Directory API](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/dev-overview) contains a number of useful APIs. But the [documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/login-user-via-api) suggests that login should be handled with hand written login pages. This is a big hassle.

Is there no way to use Cloud Directory API with delegated login pages? Is it possible to convert a SAML token or OpenID Connect token into an oauth2 token (which both support delegated login)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this would be:

1. Use OpenID to authenticate users, since it supports delegating the login screen
2. Store a OneLogin API secret & id on our server, which allows us to call all the Cloud Directory APIs without having a user's access_token

Although this may not satisfy the principle of least privilege (since we have to give our server readall permissions).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an IdP ( or Authorization server for OAuth2/OIDC ) is to delegate authentication to that service, including the authentication challenges. Coding custom authentication screens should not be required unless you have very specific branding requiements that can't be met by Onelogin ( or Okta or Auth0 etc.... )

By delegating to a third party authentication provider, you remove the ability for custom authentication screens to become bad actors with regards capturing your users credentials. When leveraging SAML or OIDC, the application itself never sees the user creds.

So, unless I've misinterpreted your question, Onelogin does exactly what you're looking for ( as do other IDaaS/IdPs ). You just need to trigger your preferred SSO protocol.